# Analog of Simplex Method for Quadratic Programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

It happened so I need to work with an algorithm for solving QP problems. The main issue here is that I can't find any references to this algorithms (at least no references in sources in english). There is something on Wikipedia, but rather obscure.
I was able to find a couple of books where this algorithm is refered to as 'Sigular Points Method' (exact translation from Russian to English), but **I want to know if there is globally accepted name for this algorithm, and maybe existing implementations in Matlab, Maple or SciPy**.

The algorithm looks like some kind of 'Simplex Method', but for QP problems, and it always converges in finite number of steps.

*Brief algorithm description:*

**We have the following QP problem**:

\begin{equation}
f(x) \to \min, \quad x \in D,
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D = \{ x \in R^n \, | \, Ax \leq b \},
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

where
$$
f: R^n \to R, \quad f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \langle Cx, x\rangle  + \langle c, x\rangle
$$
$C \in R(n, n)$ is symmetric positive semidefinite matrix,
$c \in R^n$, $A \in R(m, n)$, $b \in R^m$.

The notation $\langle a, b\rangle $ stands for dot-product, $R(m, n)$ is a set of all $(m \times n)$-dimensional matrices.

Next, let's define an analog of simplex vertices we iterate over in 'Simplex Method'.

**Definition 1.** Point $\hat x$ is called *singular* for the problem (1), (2), if exists a set $I \subset \{ 1, \ldots, m \} $, such as $\hat x$ is a solution for the following problem:

\begin{equation}
f(x) \to min, \quad x \in D_I,
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
D_I = \{ x \in R^n \, | \, \langle a_i, x\rangle = b_i, \, i \in I \}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

(cases when $I = \emptyset$ and $I = \{ 1, \ldots, m \}$ are both included).

Ok, now let's formulate a theorem that will shed some light on the actual algorithm.

**Theorem 1.** For every symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $ C \in R(n, n) $, and every $c \in R^n$, $A \in R(m, n)$ and $b \in R^m$ there is only a finite set of *singular points* for problem (1), (2), and solution of this problem is its *singular point*.

At this step it is clear that we could iterate over *singular points*, and pick the one where the value of the objective function is minimal, and that one *singular point* will be the solution.

Of course the iteration process is rather complex. It builds a sequence of *singular points* $x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^k$ such that $ f( x^{i+1} ) < f(x^i) $. Conjugate gradien method with some modifications for semidefinite matrices could be used to solve the problem (3), (4) (for quadratic functions it converges in finite number of steps).

I could provide even more details, but I'm pretty sure that at this point the algorithm could be identified.

**Edit:**

*The main idea of algorithm:*

Suppose, we have some point $x_0 \in D$.

1. Select the constraints from (2) that is satisfied as an equations for $x_0$. This constraints define some face $D_0$ of a polyhedron described by (2).
2. Find $\hat x_0 = \min f(x), \, x \in D_0$.

$\hat x_0$ is either the solution for the problem (1), (2) or it is possible to switch to another face, and start with step 1).

By the way, there is no non-negative constraints on problem variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I have successfully identified the method described above. If I got it right, it is called an **Active Set** method for quadratic programming. In particular, as @Daryl menthioned, there is a 'quadprog' function in Matlab, which solves QPP, and supports 'active set' algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you ate thinking of, but there is Wolfe's method, which is an extended simplex method. A description can be found [here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~berndm/CSE460/Lectures/cse460-5b.pdf) and in *Winston, Operations Research: Applications and Algorithms*.

Comment: I looked over the details on Wolfe's method, and I don't think it is it. Wolfe's method is only applied to QPP with non-negative problem variables, while there is no such restrictions in a problem described above. And in general, Wolfe's method and algorithm described above doesn't seem similar to me.

Comment: @Deshene I wasn't sure, but I do know this is suitable. Your problem can be rewritten in this form by setting $x=x_+ - x_-$, where $x_+$ and $x_-$ are both positive. All the best for finding the algorithm.

Comment: @Deshene I just read your edit. Again, I'm not certain of the implementation, but the [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) function in the MATLAB optimisation toolbox may be helpful to you.

Comment: about $x = x_+ - x_-$ - yes, this is a common technique, but it increases problem dimensionality twice, which is not that good. Quadprog, though, could be really helpful, thanks!